# Why the function setCredentials() cannot be found in my code?

Tags: development-environment

please check blow code for my question on the title.

The dependency is all the imports, the problem is it always reminds dependency problem and prevent me to connect with GCP.

```
    import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
    import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
    
    import java.io.*;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.channels.Channels;
    import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    
    import com.google.cloud.storage.*;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
    import com.google.auth.Credentials;
    import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
    import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
    import com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions;
    import com.google.cloud.*;

public class wordCountKaggle{
    //input should be children_kernel-children_kernel_version parent_kernel-parent_kernel_version
    //move to google cloud
    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "project_id";
    private static final String PATH_TO_JSON_KEY = "someone_f1d6897f39c3.json";
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "bucket_id";
    private static final String FOLDER_NAME = "input_file.csv";
    private static final long bucketMetageneration = 1;
    private static Storage storage;
        public void getRemoteContent() throws IOException {
                GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY)).createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
                storage = StorageOptions
                        .newBuilder()
                        .setCredentials(credentials)
                        .build()
                        .getService();
            }
}
```

Error information is as blow:

```
Error:(37, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setCredentials(com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials)
  location: class com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.Builder
```

This code works well sometime, but after I did the migration of dependency, the imports do not work anymore, and not sure which dependency is missing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have, including the imports you have at the top. Then add the full error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: Pleas check updated question.

Comment: Hi @WangSarah! Which dependency did you migrate, from which version, and to which version? When you say it works well sometimes, do you mean it worked well before the migration, but doesn't now, or that after the migration, it will work or not work at random?

Comment: thanks for the check. I did not migrate on version, just the moving of dependency libraries, from one folder from another folder for convenience. And before the location change, the connection works fine to read bucket from GCP, but after location change, the method setCredentials() cannot be found anymore.

Comment: Yep. Before the movement, it also works randomly, so I am also trying to find a way to make the code have a stable base.